# expecting initial declarator before functions when i put header file in

Tags: c++

For some reason when I put my header file in I get this error: expected init-declarator before "int" (or void)

main:

```
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    char gender;
    float gpa;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;


    inData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Data.txt");
    outData.open("./Ch7_Ex4Dataout.txt");

    inData >> gender >> gpa;
    outData << gender << gpa << endl;


    inData.close();
    outData.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

other function:

```
#include "header.h"

void initialize (int& countFemale, int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, float& sumMaleGPA)
{
            countFemale = 0;
            countMale = 0;
            sumFemaleGPA = 0;
            sumMaleGPA = 0;
}
```

header:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void extern initialize(int&, int&, float&, float&)


#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing semicolon in your declaration of `initialize`.

```
void extern initialize(int&, int&, float&, float&);  // <---- here
```